# I am running docker container on gpu node of a cluster, the container has opencv window. How can I view GUI output of container running on cluster

Tags: docker, x11

I am running docker container on cluster gpu node and incountering error when app shows GUI.

Below are the current steps that I follow.

1. `SSH` into headnode with `-X`
2. `SSH gpu02` to get on to gpu node
3. run container: `docker run  -it -e DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix  --gpus all --ipc=host imagename:tagname`
4. I come inside the container and fire python script which should idealy open opencv window with object detections, but eventually program breaks with msg:  : cannot connect to X server

Comment: not an opencv problem. replicate using `xclock` or whatever.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried, but it's not working either.

Comment: good, then it's not an OpenCV problem AND you know it's a general GUI problem. go and google. you don't think you're the first to have this problem? please take the [tour] and review [ask]